# Does sonar skip <code> tags in commented out code?

Tags: sonarqube

I am trying to figure out whether sonar can identify commented out  tags . These tags contain some valid code lines which should not be marked as a violation. Currently, the whole highlighted part is marked as a major violation. We need to skip this violation. I know people will suggest to mark it is a false positive but we can't keep on marking every violation of this type. Is there a permanent solution available? This type of commenting is valid as per Microsoft standards : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9w4cf933 [image]

Comment: Which version of the C# plugin are you using? There is a JIRA ticket on this subject which has been fixed in version 2.1: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARCS-297

Comment: In this case, I suggest you post your issue on the SonarQube users mailing list, this definitely looks like a bug in the rule.